# Python re and regex not matching my patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have an XML that I need to edit (1k+ lines) and the changes involve multiple lines in some cases. Then, my solution until this moment has been working the xml as a file opened as a string.

The line I'm looking to change is:

```
<p class=\"DailyReadingImage\" field=\"heading\"><img src=\"../Final/Images/$1.$2 Spanish.png\" style=\"real-height: 0.25in; real-width: 0.25in; width: 50%\" /></p>
```

To only be `<p />`.

According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H3aZ88/1) my pattern for looking and replacing should be:

`<p( class=\"[^\"]+\")??( style=\"[^\"]+\")??.+<img[^>]+><.p>`

This is the current version of the function:

```
import re

def repLine(k, f, r): # Key, File (a string at this point), Replacement
    fi = re.sub(re.compile(k), r, fi)
    return fi
```

But when I try `print(repLine(k, f, r))` it doesn't return the string with those changes.

Trying to print matches in order to investigate only returns `[('',''), ('',''), ('','')]` (since there's three of these lines I need to replace).
I've tried importing `re` and `regex as re` with no positive results. Any suggestions?

NOTE: Regex were in PCRE2, I changed them to Python format.

1. I've tried `fi = fi.replace(k, r)`
2. I've also tried creating a bucket with `re.findall()` and loop through it to replace.
3. Tried going line by line but some lines require multiline search ('\n').

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75687932/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: That said, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: What is it you are looking to do conceptually? can you provide examples of the text you start with and what you hope to have as an end result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: To be completely honest, no. I get the idea that using a parser is better. But what happens when I want to replace elements and their content?

Comment: Hi. Your regex is actually this `<p.+<img[^>]+><.p>` https://regex101.com/r/hAXjPj/1 If there are certain **p** attributes and certain **img** attributes that will qualify the span of `<p..> to </p>` you should mention that so I can write you a regex that replaces the block with `<p/>`